# Google News API not available?

Tags: google-search-api

I use Google news API: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=cow', but I have this message as a result:
'{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "This API is no longer available.", "responseStatus": 403}'.
Is there a solution to use Google news API?

Comment: Some other third party solution: https://serpapi.com/news-results

Comment: Aylien provides a News API that gives you access to NLP-enriched news articles from 80,000+ news sources: https://aylien.com/product/news-api/demo

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative API to search for aggregated news, you could consider Newsriver (https://newsriver.io). It's API allows to search for online news articles. Newsriver covers a large number of sources, it provides access to standardised structured news and comes with a extended search syntax based on Lucene query syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gapi ([https://gapi.xyz](https://gapi.xyz/)), the developpers basically recreated the same API but much simpler to use and it's totaly free. But you'll get a maximum of 20 results per requests. Anyway it is reasonable for a normal usage.

Comment: now is limited, 100 requests per day.

Comment: You can try this service from Rapid API https://rapidapi.com/anju.313/api/google-trends